# Input a text file, the output date format is missing

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS. I have an input txt file and uploaded it to my working directory, when I read and format the DATE_JOINED column, the date is missing, code as following:

```
    data example_txt;
    infile '/home/u59667351/example_csv/example_csv.txt' dlm='<|>' firstobs=2;
    input PERSON_ID $ DEPT_ID $ DATE_JOINED yymmdd10. ;
    format DATE_JOINED yymmdd10.;
run;
```

the text file named example_csv as following:

```
PERSON_ID<|>DEPT_ID<|>DATE_JOINED
AAAAA<|>S1<|>2021/01/03
BBBBBB<|>S2<|>2021/02/03
CCCCC<|>S1<|>2021/03/05
```

The OUTPUT date for DATE_JOINED column is missing.

[image]

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Your code and output DO NOT MATCH.  Your code shows a data set named example_txt but the file shown is example_csv so I think you may be looking at the wrong file possibly?

Comment: Yap, you are right. Because I tried both CSV and txt files and all don't work. Now it's solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not just an issue with the looking at the right file try using an INFORMAT statement instead, slightly cleaner.

```
data example_txt;
infile '/home/u59667351/example_csv/example_csv.txt' dlm='<|>' firstobs=2;
informat person_id $8. DEPT_ID $8. date_joined yymmdd10.;
input PERSON_ID  DEPT_ID  DATE_JOINED  ;
format DATE_JOINED yymmdd10.;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes in your data step.

First is you are using the `DLM=` INFILE option when it looks like you meant to use the `DLMSTR=` option.  When you list multiple characters in the DLM= option each individual character is treated as a delimiter. With DLMSTR= option the whole sequence must appear exactly as specified to be treated as a delimiter.

Second is you are trying to read DATE_JOINED using FORMATTED input mode, which defeats the purpose of reading delimited data. Since the cursor is pointing after the `<` that marked the end of the DEPT_ID value the next 10 characters do not represent a valid date.  With LIST mode input any leading delimiters are skipped over before starting to read the next value from the file.

When using an informat specification in an INPUT statement prefix it with the `:` modifier to use LIST input mode instead of FORMATTED mode.
Or remove the in-line informat and use an INFORMAT statement to set the informat you want to use when reading text into that variable.

You probably also want to add the TRUNCOVER option on the INFILE statement so the INPUT statement will not go to the next line to find a value when the last value(s) are empty.

```
data example_txt;
  infile '/home/u59667351/example_csv/example_csv.txt'
      dlmstr='<|>' firstobs=2 truncover
  ;
  input PERSON_ID $ DEPT_ID $ DATE_JOINED :yymmdd. ;
  format DATE_JOINED yymmdd10.;
run;
```

PS When using LIST mode input the width on your informat specification is ignored.  The whole next value on the line is used however many characters it contains.